# How to merge multiple rows into one list rather then separate lists? - no pandas just csv

Tags: python, list, merge

I have multiple rows from a CSV file that need to be merged to create one list.

My data set will look like this;

```
column 1       column 2   column3      column 4 ....... all the way to column 10
A              1           2             3                  4 5 6 7 8 9 10
B              5           10            15                  16 17 18 19 20
```

Currently my code will look like this:

```py
cd1 = []
cd2 = []
cd3 = []
cd4 = []
cd5 = []
cd6 = []
cd7 = []
cd8 = []
cd9 = []
cd10 = []


#create lists with values from rows 
for row in physiciancounts:
    patID.append(row[0]) 
    cd1.append(row[2])
    cd2.append(row[3])
    cd3.append(row[4])
    all the way till row 10

# then I'll merge it using zip
```

I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this instead of creating multiple lists and merging them together.

the output would look something like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
(5,10,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

I'm not including the first column because that will need to be a separate list. I'm not getting an error; I just want to see if there is a better way of doing this. Still a newbie to python, so I am struggling. I also can't do the one-line for loops for the scope of what I am doing.

Comment: It's hard to see what you are trying to ask without a sample of your input data. Could you provide just a few lines of the actual CSV, ideally to produce the expected output you already show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, just add another loop.

```py
column_count = 10
cd = [[]] * column_count
for row in physiciancounts:
    for field in range(column_count):
        cd[field].append(row[field])
```

This needlessly collects the second column, too (which you call "first" in your question, i.e. index 1); if you want to avoid that, maybe add `if field != 1:` inside the `for` loop.

Your question is also unclear on whether there are 10 or 11 columns; maybe use `column_count = 11` if necessary.